# How to test NodeJS fs using Mocha/Chai/Sinon?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon

I want to test the below method from my History class using Mocha/Chai/Sinon, how?

```
/**
 * Load the history from the history file.
 * @return {this}
 */
load() {
  const file = historyFilePath();

  if (!fs.existsSync(file)) {
    return this;
  }

  const json = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8');
  const data = JSON.parse(json);

  this.ary = data;

  return this;
}
```

The full class is [here](https://github.com/maasha/rpncalc/blob/master/app/utils/history.util.js).

I have noted the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829963/unit-test-a-node-js-application-with-mocha-chai-and-sinon) depending on rewire, but I want to avoid the extra dependency and rewire is also not compatible with babel.

Comment: You can use Sinon [`stubs`](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.2.0/stubs/).

Comment: @robertklep I have noted that, I just can't get it to work.

Comment: If you share the code that isn't working, it's much easier for people to help you.

Comment: @robertklep I better admit that I don't know where to start when it comes to sinon stubs and testing fs. I am afraid there is no test code yet.

Comment: Here's something to get you started: https://gist.github.com/robertklep/6f6b9aacf80f16334883c647d41c9d12 It stubs `fs.existsSync` to always return false, and the stub is also used to check if it gets called with the correct filename.

Comment: Hm, I get a `TypeError: Attempted to wrap existsSync which is already wrapped`?https://gist.github.com/maasha/ff4451f0b4feb61155273e573f2f9a57

Comment: I updated the gist (same URL). The issue is that when an assertion tails, `stub.restore()` doesn't get called and `fs.existsSync()` therefore isn't "unwrapped". One fix for that is to use a sandbox and restore it after each test.

Answer (score 0):

One way, assuming the HistoryFile always has the same structure, is to test if you're getting an object with the correct properties.

For example if your History JSON file would like this

```
{
    "History": {
        "Name": "Test"
    }
}
```

You could write your mocha like this:

```
it('should return a correct object', function() {
  const loadedObject = historyUtil.load();

  expect(loadedObject).to.have.property("History");
  expect(loadedObject.History).to.have.property("Name","Test");
}
```

This test should fail if:

1. FS can't find/read the file
2. JSON.parse doesn't get a parsable string
3. The HistoryFile schema would change, e.g. version changes.

Comment: Right, but I would like to stub the fs - which is the proper way to test in case the file system is inaccessible or over a slow remote connection.